# React-native bridge is nil when method called from Swift ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have a class to send events defined as follows:

```
import UIKit

@objc(NativeEventSender)
class NativeEventSender: RCTEventEmitter {
    override func supportedEvents() .. {
      return ["Supported Event"]
    }

    @objc func sendEventToJS(_ titleString: String) {
        self.sendEvent(withName: "Event", body: titleString)
    }
}
```

This class is exposed to Objective-C using `RCT_EXTERN_MODULE()` and `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` for the `sendEventToJS` method.

The `sendEventToJS` method is called in my `ViewController.swift`. This `ViewController` is exposed to React-Native through a `UIView` that is returned by a view manager.

Now every time the `sendEventToJS` function is fired, the app crashes because the `Bridge` is `nil`, with a message saying it wasn't set. The view otherwise renders properly. I have already tried converting the Obj-C example in the documentation to Swift. Tried everything from the sending event issue on the react-native repository and it still doesn't work. Have also tried a few examples on Github where the `sendEvent(withName, body)` method was used. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using webbridge to communicate to your web server ?

Comment: No, this is a standard bridge.

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this? I am also having the same problem and finding it hard to find a tutorial. I cannot emit events to JS from Swift UI components.

Comment: I did, but I ended up using the bridge that was established for displaying the native component in the first place and piggybacking the event emitter on that. Do you have a demo repository I could help you debug?